# CarrierWave File Upload store_dir in parent association

Tags: ruby-on-rails, carrierwave

I have an association setup between a Request model and a Document model. Each Request `has_many` Documents and each Document `belongs_to` a Request. Uploading files and storing them into a folder works great. Currently, my `store_dir` method looks like this:

```
def store_dir
  "uploads/Requests/#{model.id}"
end
```

However, I was wondering how I would save the files by request.id and then model.id:

```
def store_dir
  "uploads/#{request.id}/#{model.id}"
end
```

Is this possible? Hoping someone could point me in the right direction. I'm not sure how to pass the request id into the DocumentUploader.

*If more information needs to be provided please let me know!*

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As `model` is the ActiveRecord instance that mounts the uploader you should be able to use the ActiveRecord associations. Since you state that `Document` `belongs_to` a `Request` (and I assume that `Document` is the ActiveRecord that mounts the uploader) you can get the `Request`'s id with `model.request_id` (or `model.request.id`).

```
def store_dir
  "uploads/#{model.request_id}/#{model.id}"
end
```

Comment: Wow. Thank you so much!

Comment: This works but in case the same `Carrierwave Uploader` would be used across parent models (shared between them), a different approach must be used. I mean, if both `Requests` and `Invoices` use `Documents`, then the code must extract the parent `id` from either `request_id` or `invoice_id`. Any ideas are highly welcome.

Comment: @W.M. In this case a method `def parent_id` or similar on each of the models should return the required id. E.g.: `def parent_id  request_id end`. Then you can change `store_dir` to `"uploads/#{model.parent_id}/#{model.id}"`.

Comment: @koffeinfrei, thank you. I have managed to extract the `id` by regex searching properties' names of the model inside `store_dir`

Comment: @W.M. I'd **really** recommend avoiding regexes for such cases and using a proper OO pattern to encapsulate the behaviour in each specific class. This adheres to the SRP, as the uploader just asks the model class to tell it the information it needs. Using a regex inside `store_dir` is A) the wrong tool (regex) and B) violates the SRP.